# pull down resistor in PIR circuit

Tags: resistors, level-shifting, pullup, pulldown

I have an motion sensor circuit. The circuit calls for a voltage of 2-15 dc volts. On the PIR data sheet the source pins calls for a pull down resistor of 47K at 5 volts. My question is if I use 8 volts on the circuit do I need to recalculate the source pin resistor? I have searched this forum and others for the usage of higher or lower voltage, but cannot seem to find any examples. All examples are made around 5 volt.

Sorry . I do not have a data sheet on the circuit. I am using PIR325 on the circuit I have now and it calls for a 100R resistor and it seems to be rather slow. I am using 8 volts on it and I have the circuit tied into a PICAXE 08m2. I also have a regulator and a diode for the voltage on the picaxe. I am posting a picture of the schematic for the circuit without the picaxe. The picaxe is tied into the circuit a the large dot next to the led. I want to change PIR to a PIR LHI878. Here is the data on the PIR. excelitas.com/downloads/dts_lhi778_lhi878_pyd1388.pdf – [image]

Comment: "On the datasheet" in your post and no link to a datasheet and no copy of the schematic is a little unfair on us. Could you add anything that helps us understand the question by way of schematics, images or links?

Comment: Sorry . I do not have a data sheet on the circuit. I am using PIR325 on the circuit I have now and it calls for a 100R resistor and it seems to be rather slow. I am using 8 volts on it and I have the circuit tied into a PICAXE 08m2. I also have a regulator and a diode for the voltage on the picaxe. I am posting a picture of the schematic for the circuit without the picaxe. The picaxe is tied into the circuit a the large dot next to the led. I want to change PIR to a PIR LHI878. Here is the data on the PIR.
http://www.excelitas.com/downloads/dts_lhi778_lhi878_pyd1388.pdf

Comment: I have a schematic of the circuit but I do not know how to post it.

Comment: @CalvinFluitt Take a screenshot of it, and upload it here and provide a link to the schematic if it was from an online source.

Comment: I went to edit and was able to attach schematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to [calculate](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/orderops.htm) it the [mathematical](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/ratio.htm) way, set it up as a ratio and solve for X:

47k / 5v = x / 8v

Get rid of "/8" by doing the opposite to the left:

(47 * 8) / 5 = x

376 / 5 = x

x = 73k. That will provide a scaled pull-down resistor value for 8v instead of 5v. We can check the actual current by using [Ohm's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law). Assuming the full supply voltage was being imposed across the pulldown resistor,

```
I = E / R       I = E / R
I = 5v / 47k    I = 8v / 73k
I = 0.000106A   I = 0.000109A
I = 106uA       I = 109uA
```

Close enough. Give it a try, should work just fine. Test a +/-20% variance and see what effect it has on the circuit. I doubt the value is super-critical, but one particular value may work best.

73k * 0.20 + 73k = 87.6k

73k - 73k * 0.20 = 58.4k

If a particular pull-down current is specified as best, then calculate the resistor value for the given operating voltage by:

E = I * R

R = E / I

R = 12v / 100uA

R = 120k

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyuRcsM0gjI

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer, given all the information (including the datasheet you linked in the comments: Pro-tip, add it to your post, preferably at the first posting, to get the best answers the most quickly), is: No need to change the resistor.

If you change the supply voltage of the Sensor to between 5V and 12V, anywhere, the response will be in large orders the same. The "at 5V" in the datasheet is sort of to make it clear that the sensor will not achieve that output when you power it with only 2V.

The only thing that should change in this schematic, provided all the op-amps used are actually the ones in the schematic, is the set-points of the potentiometers, but you are probably going to empirically find them anyway. (The point about the op-amps is that not all op-amps in the world will work with a single-ended supply and/or one above 5V, but the LM3xx-series op-amps will do you perfectly fine in most use cases for this schematic.)

So, no, you need not change anything in this schematic. The changes in response from the sensor will be minimal and the effect of the changes is easily caught with the trim potentiometers "RV1" and "RV2".

You are allowed to experiment with other resistors, such as 22k or 68k or 91k to see if the response and filtering will match your application more, but it should not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Update on what I have tested.
Changed to 47K and 12 volts but the sensor would not settle down. Just stayed on the blink. Changed to 12 volts 75K and the same thing happened. Changed to 8 volts and 47k and the sensor worked well sensed up to 70 feet and was responsive. Changed to 8 volts and 75K and worked very well. sensed up the 90 feet and was very responsive. Before I decided on what to use I will continue to test other resistors that were suggested. I will update when completed. Thank You